# jQuery hover animation only between different classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/0oh7hvja/) code

HTML:

```
<div class="random">div 1</div>
<div class="random animation">div 2</div>
<div class="random animation">div 3</div>

<div class="random animated">Fade</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

$( ".animation" ).hover(

    function() {
        $( ".animated" ).hide( 500 );


    }, function() {
        $( ".animated" ).show( 500 );


    }
);

});
```

How not to trigger animation when switching between div 2 and div 3 ?
I guess it's simple...

---

One problem with `stop()`, actually i'm using

```
addClass( "uk-animation-reverse uk-animation-scale-down" )
```

and

```
removeClass( "uk-animation-reverse" )
```

to control animation =/ is it work this way or any other ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply [**`stop`**](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) the animation if it's running between each element's hover event:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
  $(".animation" ).hover(
    function() {
      $( ".animated" ).stop().hide( 500 );
    }, function() {
      $( ".animated" ).stop().show( 500 );
    }
  );
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vers9bu0/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the propagation of the animation before when it is triggered with the same selector `.animated`

**code**

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
  $(".animation" ).hover(
    function() {

      $( ".animated" ).stop().hide( 500 );

    }, function() {

      $( ".animated" ).stop().show( 500 );

    }
  );
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0oh7hvja/5/)**